# How to phrase query a SQLite FTS table using prefix?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, intersect

I'm in a situation where i need to do a FTS query which matches on multiple fields, but for some reason when doing a query looking for a "phrase" using the prefix i'm getting extra results because it's not matching the whole query.

For instance:

***SELECT favorite,cd_title, content, is_child, parent FROM blazing WHERE blazing MATCH  'cd_title:Industry - Sport - Pop 1'***

Will return 141 results on my query, while

***SELECT favorite,cd_title, content, is_child, parent FROM blazing WHERE cd_title MATCH  'Industry - Sport - Pop 1'***

Will fetch ( precisely ) the 58 records i need.

This wouldn't be a problem if i didn't have to deal with multiple fields while searching.

A workaround i found is:

***SELECT favorite, content, is_child, parent FROM blazing WHERE ROWID IN
(
    SELECT ROWID from blazing WHERE cd_title MATCH "Industry - Sport - Pop 1"
)***

but that would mean having to do multiple queries and INTERSECT them in order to do a query matching multiple fields.

I tried using single quotes and double quotes around the phrase but it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you edit and complete the last sentence please?

Comment: absolutely, sorry something went wrong here, prob a cmd + z by accident

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994838/fts-sqlite-phrase-search-for-single-column-not-possible. Apparently you can not do a phrase search for a specific column, so in your first example you search for "Industry" in the title and everything else in all fields. I solved my similar problem using a subselect and put that as an answer in the linked question.